# How can I write a batch file to execute my Python script with argument

Tags: python, batch-file, arguments

I have some python script

```
def task(start, stop):
    #"doing something with start and stop"
    return 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("input start, stop")
    start = int(input())
    stop = int(input())
    task(start,stop)
```

I run my script by CMD command "python task.py"
If I input

> start = 1 and stop = 1000

My script running very slow. I could open 10 CMD windows then input

> start = 1, stop = 10 in CMD first

> start = 11, stop = 20 in CMD second

... and finally start = 90, stop = 100 in final CMD

How can I write a BAT file to run instead of open 10 CMD windows then input by myself.

Comment: for not just a python file and multi processing ?

Comment: It would be much better if your Python script would accept arguments to define `start` and `stop` value as options on command line and would prompt the user for the `start` and/or the `stop` value only if the appropriate argument was not specified on Python script command line. That would make it possible to use a batch file with a __FOR__ loop much easier. For example, see [Command Line Arguments in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-python/).

Comment: It would be also better to run `python.exe` for interpreting your Python script with suitable `start` and `stop` values not more often than the number of cores of your CPU minus 1. One core should be reserved for Windows and all other running processes and the other 1 to X cores can be used to run 1 to X `python.exe task.py start=n stop=m` or `(echo n& echo m) | python.exe task.py` if the Python script is not enhanced to support optional arguments for `start` and `stop` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for @mofi
I could write this batch file to solve my problems

```
@echo off    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (0,10,99) do (
set /a result=%%i + 9
start cmd /k "(echo %%i & echo !result! ) | python task.py"
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it full python

In parallel with `multiprocessing`

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def task(params):
    start, stop = params
    print(start, stop)

with Pool(10) as p:
    results = p.map(task, [(i, i + 9) for i in range(1, 100, 10)])
```

Sequentially with a loop

```
def task(start, stop):
    print(start, stop)

for i in range(1, 100, 10):
    task(i, i + 9)
```

---

Both will execute the 10 following calls

```
1 10
11 20
21 30
31 40
41 50
51 60
61 70
71 80
81 90
91 100
```

Comment: I dont want use multiprocessing because my task is complicated, is there any way to do with batch file?

Comment: @duydang I have proposed you a solution with a simple for loop, why not do that ? Also openning 10 terminal IS LIKE multiprocessing, that just means run them **at the same time** that changes nothing in python in your code, you don't have to change the task code at all

Comment: I have try but as I say, my script is complicated. So can not use multiprocessing. In my task function using some global variable. If i using multiprocessing some error come up variable is not defined. So I try using batch file.